# Running grunt and compiling sass to the same directory as source files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-sass

I have all of my scss under parent folder and I have a grunt task running to compile them.

With this particular project there won't be a build or output folder. I would like to have all of the scss files compile in their same directory.

`+ folder
  + component
    - style.scss
    - style.css
  + another
    - style.scss
    - style.css`

I have search high and low and can't find any examples of this. Is it even possible with Grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out and wanted to post this just incase anyone else needed to achieve this.

the cwd and dest need to be the same value.

```
dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true, // Recursive
                cwd: "<%= pathTo.Root %>", // The startup directory
                src: '**/*.{sass,scss}', // Source files
                dest: "<%= pathToRoot %>",
                ext: ".css" // File extension 
            }]
        }
```